# Is it possible to select a random icon in Icons or FontAwesomeIcons, etc

Tags: dart, flutter

**Context:**

I'm discovering both flutter and dart. And I'm only doing app for my own pleasure.

**My Objective**

I would like to make a stupid app that display a random icon on each day (like word of the day).

However I'm not sure how to proceed at this time. In all examples the code directly references the IconData field that are declared in respective classes like `FontAwesomeIcons` or `Icons` for material icons.

These fields are declared as `static const`. What would be the most correct way to access those fields in order to say *put them in a list where I can randomly pick an index* ?

```dart
library font_awesome_flutter;

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/icon_data.dart';

// THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED!

class FontAwesomeIcons {
  static const IconData fiveHundredPx = const IconDataBrands(0xf26e);
  static const IconData accessibleIcon = const IconDataBrands(0xf368);
  static const IconData accusoft = const IconDataBrands(0xf369);
```

````dart
// Copyright 2015 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// Identifiers for the supported material design icons.
///
/// Use with the [Icon] class to show specific icons.
///
/// Icons are identified by their name as listed below.
///
/// To use this class, make sure you set `uses-material-design: true` in your
/// project's `pubspec.yaml` file in the `flutter` section. This ensures that
/// the MaterialIcons font is included in your application. This font is used to
/// display the icons. For example:
///
/// ```yaml
/// name: my_awesome_application
/// flutter:
///   uses-material-design: true
/// ```
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Icon]
///  * [IconButton]
///  * [design.google.com/icons](https://design.google.com/icons/)
class Icons {
  Icons._();

  // Generated code: do not hand-edit.
  // See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Updating-Material-Design-Fonts
  // BEGIN GENERATED

  /// <i class="material-icons md-36">360</i> &#x2014; material icon named "360".
  static const IconData threesixty = IconData(0xe577, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');

  /// <i class="material-icons md-36">3d_rotation</i> &#x2014; material icon named "3d rotation".
  static const IconData threed_rotation = IconData(0xe84d, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
````

Answer (score 6):

Just use the `Icon(IconData())` constructor.

```
  final List<int> points = <int>[0xe0b0, 0xe0b1, 0xe0b2, 0xe0b3, 0xe0b4];
  final Random r = Random();

  Icon randomIcon() =>
    Icon(IconData(r.nextInt(points.length), fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'));
```

populate your table of points with some values of the characters in the chosen font face.

If you prefer, just create a list of the icons by name like this:

```
  final List<IconData> iconData = <IconData>[Icons.call, Icons.school];

  Icon randomIcon2() => Icon(iconData[r.nextInt(iconData.length)]);
```

Comment: I have thought about this, but this requires a tedious copy off all possible values found in these constant classes, I don't want a subset of icons I'd like my app to possibly show any icon available in these classes. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
IconData getRandomIcon(){
  final List<int> points = <int>[0xe0b0, 0xe0b1, 0xe0b2, 0xe0b3, 0xe0b4];
  final Random random = Random();
  const String chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  int length = 3;
  String hex = '0xe';
  while(length-- > 0) hex += chars[(random.nextInt(16)) | 0];
  return IconData(int.parse(hex), fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
}
```

Comment: it's really amazing. perfect answer as per requirement